# Running office script in every column - for loop?

Tags: office-scripts

Trying to accomplish something I assume is quite simple but I am just relying on my old knowledge of coding to amend this function to work for my needs.

I just want the below function to run in every column in the sheet from C onwards. It simply counts the number of highlighted yellow or blue cells and places that count at the top. Currently works fine for column C but as stated just want this to run in every single column.

Thanks a bunch!

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
    let dayRange = selectedSheet.getRange("C26:C59");
    let dayCount = selectedSheet.getRange("C26:C59").getCellCount();
    let dayColorCode = selectedSheet.getRange("C9").getFormat().getFill().getColor();
    let dayCounter = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < dayCount; i++) {
        if (dayRange.getCell(i, 0).getFormat().getFill().getColor() == dayColorCode) {
            dayCounter = dayCounter + 1;
        }
    }

    selectedSheet.getRange("C9").setValue(dayCounter);

    let nightRange = selectedSheet.getRange("C60:C70");
    let nightCount = selectedSheet.getRange("C60:C70").getCellCount();
    let nightColorCode = selectedSheet.getRange("C10").getFormat().getFill().getColor();

    let nightCounter = 0;

    for (let j = 0; j < dayCount; j++) {
        if (nightRange.getCell(j, 0).getFormat().getFill().getColor() == nightColorCode) {
            nightCounter = nightCounter + 1;
        }
    }

    selectedSheet.getRange("C10").setValue(nightCounter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path of least resistence, it's crude but should work.  Also, I can't imagine that it will be quick.  Also untested.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
  let columnCount = selectedSheet.getRange().getColumnCount();

  for (let column = 3; column <= columnCount; column++) {
    let columnLetter = selectedSheet.getCell(0, column).getAddress().split("!")[1].replace("1", "");

    let dayRange = selectedSheet.getRange(columnLetter + "26:" + columnLetter + "59");
    let dayCount = selectedSheet.getRange(columnLetter + "26:" + columnLetter + "59").getCellCount();
    let dayColorCode = selectedSheet.getRange(columnLetter + "9").getFormat().getFill().getColor();
    let dayCounter = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < dayCount; i++) {
        if (dayRange.getCell(i, 0).getFormat().getFill().getColor() == dayColorCode) {
            dayCounter = dayCounter + 1;
        }
    }

    selectedSheet.getRange(columnLetter + "9").setValue(dayCounter);

    let nightRange = selectedSheet.getRange(columnLetter + "60:" + columnLetter + "70");
    let nightCount = selectedSheet.getRange(columnLetter + "60:" + columnLetter + "70").getCellCount();
    let nightColorCode = selectedSheet.getRange(columnLetter + "10").getFormat().getFill().getColor();

    let nightCounter = 0;

    for (let j = 0; j < dayCount; j++) {
        if (nightRange.getCell(j, 0).getFormat().getFill().getColor() == nightColorCode) {
            nightCounter = nightCounter + 1;
        }
    }

    selectedSheet.getRange(columnLetter + "10").setValue(nightCounter);
  }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it! It worked as intended but still wasn't an ideal solution so I started teaching myself JS and built a better script from scratch that implements Power Automate flows. Thanks for the response though!